# spark tuning optimize running times with executors

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When I run a spark streaming app is it possible to get better running times for 4 executors than for 1,2,6,10 executors?

Comment: what is your cluster configuration?

Comment: ./bin/spark-submit --class myApp --master yarn --num-executors 4 —driver-memory 1024m  --executor-memory 1024m —executor-cores 1

Comment: cluster configurationis needed(like num of nodes, ram, cores in each node etc) is needed. not your existing spark configuration.

Comment: You mean this: 3 x Dell PowerEdge R320 Intel Xeon E5-2430 v2 2.50GHz, 32GB RAM, 1TB HDD

Comment: the cpu core count is essential, please provide that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running your Spark job with 4 executors (4 different Java processes) and each of those are configured to have 1 GB of memory and only 1 core (--executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1), then that means you can only run a single worker task at a time. Increasing the number of executors using the same configurations you have will yield better results.

If you want to improve performance using only 4 executors, then increasing the number of cores will increase the level of parallelism (more worker tasks running simultaneously). However, you will most probably need more memory as the number of cores increase, and as your memory usage increases you will want to be sure you don't run into Java performance issues (Garbage Collection).

So to answer your question very briefly without any other details, you MAY theoretically be able to get better results with 4 executors with 3 or 4 cores each (12 or 16 tasks running in parallel) as opposed to 6 or 10 executors with just 1 core each (6 or 10 tasks running at a time).

Edited:

I'm ignoring your statement here about "Spark Streaming." There are a lot more considerations that can impact your Spark streaming application's performance beyond just the number of executors. In some cases, for example reading data from just one single Kafka topic partition using the direct API, increasing the number of executors and cores won't have any impact at all.